# MySQL Combining two queries with same structure and add column

Tags: mysql

## 1. I have one query to get a sum of how many users per `worksite` that appears on each date.

## 2. I have another query that gets how many documents were made on each date by worksite

Since both tables are in the same format, is it possible to take #1's value for each worksite and date and #2's value for each worksite and date, and join them so they appear in the same table on just another column?

So that it looks like this:

```
| Worksite   | Date       | Users On Site | Completed |
| ---------- | ---------- | -----------   | --------- |
| worksite_1 | 2019-01-01 | 2             | 2
| worksite_2 | 2019-01-01 | 0             | 2
| worksite_1 | 2019-01-02 | 1             | 1
| worksite_2 | 2019-01-02 | 0             | 2 
| worksite_1 | 2019-01-03 | 2             | 2            
| worksite_1 | 2019-01-04 | 1             | 1             
| worksite_2 | 2019-01-04 | 0             | 1            
| worksite_1 | 2019-01-05 | 1             | 1             
| worksite_2 | 2019-01-05 | 0             | 1            
| worksite_1 | 2019-01-06 | 1             | 1            
| worksite_2 | 2019-01-06 | 0             | 1
```

---

## #1

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE OnSite
    (`uid` varchar(55), `worksite_id`  varchar(55), `timestamp` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO OnSite
    (`uid`, `worksite_id`, `timestamp`)
VALUES
  ("u12345", "worksite_1", '2019-01-01'),
  ("u12345", "worksite_1", '2019-01-02'),
  ("u12345", "worksite_1", '2019-01-03'),
  ("u12345", "worksite_1", '2019-01-04'),
  ("u12345", "worksite_1", '2019-01-05'),
  ("u12345", "worksite_1", '2019-01-06'),
  ("u1", "worksite_1", '2019-01-01'),
  ("u1", "worksite_1", '2019-01-02'),
  ("u1", "worksite_1", '2019-01-05'),
  ("u1", "worksite_1", '2019-01-06')

;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT    worksite_id, DATE(timestamp) Date, COUNT(DISTINCT uid) `Users On Site`
FROM      OnSite
GROUP BY  DATE(timestamp), worksite_id;

| worksite_id | Date       | Users On Site |
| ----------- | ---------- | ------------- |
| worksite_1  | 2019-01-01 | 2             |
| worksite_1  | 2019-01-02 | 2             |
| worksite_1  | 2019-01-03 | 1             |
| worksite_1  | 2019-01-04 | 1             |
| worksite_1  | 2019-01-05 | 2             |
| worksite_1  | 2019-01-06 | 2             |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qtVbazaG4PT4kjqSKp2NaV/0)

---

## #2

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE Documents
    (`document_id` varchar(55), `uid` varchar(55), `worksite_id`  varchar(55), `type` varchar(55), `timestamp` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Documents
    (`document_id`, `uid`, `worksite_id`, `type`, `timestamp`)
    
VALUES
  ("1",     "u12345",   "worksite_1", 'work_permit',    '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
  ("2",     "u12345",   "worksite_2", 'job',            '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
  ("3",     "u12345",   "worksite_1", 'work_permit',    '2019-01-02 00:00:00'),
  ("4",     "u12345",   "worksite_2", 'job',            '2019-01-02 00:00:00'),
  ("5",     "u12345",   "worksite_1", 'work_permit',    '2019-01-03 00:00:00'),
  ("6",     "u12345",   "worksite_2", 'job',            '2019-01-04 00:00:00'),
  ("7",     "u12345",   "worksite_1", 'work_permit',    '2019-01-04 00:00:00'),
  ("8",     "u12345",   "worksite_2", 'work_permit',    '2019-01-05 00:00:00'),
  ("9",     "u12345",   "worksite_1", 'job',            '2019-01-05 00:00:00'),
  ("10",    "u12345",   "worksite_2", 'work_permit',    '2019-01-06 00:00:00'),
  ("11",    "u12345",   "worksite_1", 'work_permit',    '2019-01-06 00:00:00'),
  ("12",    "u12345",   "worksite_2", 'work_permit',    '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
  ("13",    "u12345",   "worksite_1", 'job',            '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
  ("14",    "u12345",   "worksite_2", 'work_permit',    '2019-01-02 00:00:00'),
  ("15",    "u12345",   "worksite_1", 'work_permit',    '2019-01-03 00:00:00')

;
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT    worksite_id 'Worksite', 
          Date(timestamp) Date,
          COUNT(worksite_id) `Completed`
FROM      Documents
GROUP BY  Date(timestamp), worksite_id;

| Worksite   | Date       | Completed |
| ---------- | ---------- | --------- |
| worksite_1 | 2019-01-01 | 2         |
| worksite_2 | 2019-01-01 | 2         |
| worksite_1 | 2019-01-02 | 1         |
| worksite_2 | 2019-01-02 | 2         |
| worksite_1 | 2019-01-03 | 2         |
| worksite_1 | 2019-01-04 | 1         |
| worksite_2 | 2019-01-04 | 1         |
| worksite_1 | 2019-01-05 | 1         |
| worksite_2 | 2019-01-05 | 1         |
| worksite_1 | 2019-01-06 | 1         |
| worksite_2 | 2019-01-06 | 1         |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ur5EpRRWqz7FUPkNc6eYwG/2)

Comment: Can you update the question and use the correct `Completed` values in the expected results based on the example data.. So we can verify the correctness of the query we possible write?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I believe I've updated it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JOIN. For example:

```
SELECT
  IFNULL(OnSite.worksite_id, Documents.worksite_id) as `Worksite`,
  DATE(IFNULL(OnSite.timestamp, Documents.timestamp)) as `Date`,
  COUNT(DISTINCT OnSite.uid) as `Users_On_Site`,
  COUNT(Documents.worksite_id) as `Completed`
FROM OnSite
  LEFT JOIN Documents ON OnSite.worksite_id = Documents.worksite_id AND DATE(OnSite.timestamp) = DATE(Documents.timestamp)
GROUP BY `Date`, `Worksite`;
```

Comment: "You can use LEFT JOIN" You know you used a INNER JOIN in the SQL right?

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try this. Not quite sure how it works: 
> Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'uid) as `Users_On_Site`, COUNT(Documents.worksite_id) as `Completed` FROM OnS' at line 3

Comment: `COUNT(OnSite.DISTINCT uid)` should be `COUNT(DISTINCT  OnSite.uid)` @bryan also `COUNT(Documents.worksite_id) as Completed might also require a `DISTINCT` if you notice values which are double which you expected.

Comment: @RaymondNijland [Any ideas for this?](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qtVbazaG4PT4kjqSKp2NaV/2)

Comment: @RaymondNijland oh, I'm sorry. It's a typo. Of course, I mean INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN

Comment: [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qtVbazaG4PT4kjqSKp2NaV/3) is how it can be written also @bryan Maxim Fedorov last update also works and is valid SQL

Comment: @brayn, Oh sorry I made few typos I fixed them.

Comment: Wow it's getting there! This is starting to make sense. Thank you guys. But I wonder why none of the completed numbers show up. Would it be because the Date formats are wrong between both databases? @RaymondNijland

Comment: Your SQLfiddle link uses other dates then your example data here @bryan

Comment: Killer. My mistake. Thanks guys!

Comment: @RaymondNijland just out of curiosity, is there a way to have another column that is Completed divided by Users on Site? I'm new to MySQL so seeing what kind of flexibility there is

Comment: @bryan you need to repeat `COUNT(Documents.worksite_id) / COUNT(DISTINCT OnSite.uid) as total`    of use a subquery `SELECT alias.*, (Completed / Users_On_Site) AS total FROM (SELECT IFNULL(OnSite.worksite_id, Documents.worksite_id) as `Worksite`... ) AS alias`... which is required in every SQL dialect.